# pip ignores python_requires field in setup

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, setup.py

I have the following in my setup.cfg file:

```
[metadata]
name = mathsom
python_requires = '>=3.8'
...
```

Problem is that I created an enviroment with Python 3.7 and installation had no problems. Installation command:

```
pip install --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ mathsom
```

Shouldn't pip require a Python 3.8 enviroment?

Here is the test.PyPI link: [PyPI project](https://test.pypi.org/project/mathsom/), and here the repo: [GitHub repo](https://github.com/oliverm91/mathsom)

I know that the setup.cfg file is working because pip install packages in `install_requires` field and Trove Classifiers show in Test PyPI.

Complete setup.cfg file:

```
[metadata]
name = mathsom
python_requires = '>=3.8'
author = Oliver Mohr B.
author_email = oliver.mohr.b@gmail.com
version = 0.1.2
description = Personal library for math related problems
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/oliverm91/mathsom
license_files = LICENSE
keywords = solvers, solver, interpolations, interpolation, numerics, derivatives, integrals
classifiers = 
    Development Status :: 3 - Alpha
    License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)
    Programming Language :: Python
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11
    Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Mathematics
    Natural Language :: English

[options]
package_dir=
    = src
packages=find:
install_requires =
    numpy
    scipy

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1787#issuecomment-524570524 : "*Note that `python_requires` belong in the `[options]` section.*"

Comment: This worked, plus I had to remove the quoting marks '>=3.8' to >=3.8.

Comment: Feel free to post as answer. For other people, just keep in mind that pip throws an error message, but it just says that it does not find the package when you try to install with a python version that does not meet this criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python_requires` belongs to section [`[options]`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#options):

```
[metadata]
name = mathsom

[options]
python_requires = >= 3.8
```